# matching two points with minimum distance

Tags: algorithm, matlab, distance, k-means, minimum

I'm working on this problem:

There is a 3d binary matrix which i cluster with the kmeans algorithm in matlab;

After that i get a value C which contains the coordinates of the centroids of these clusters in an array, for example:

```
 C=   30.0000   15.0000   48.5000   

      100.2676   57.7382   80.7489

      57.5000   85.0000   35.0000

      27.5000   50.0000   69.5000
```

(4 centroids: first one with coordinates (`30,15,48,5`))
where the rows represent the `x,y` and `z` coordinate of each centroid.

When I cluster another matrix I get a second value which also contains the coordinates of the second centroids.
now i have to match the centroids from first and second clustering which have minimum distance and create an output where i can see which centroids belong together.

I have tried it with `pdist(X)` and i get the distances pairwise of the coordinates but i can not match them together..

How to solve this, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`pdist2`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) instead of [`pdist`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html).

`pdist2` calculates the pairwise distance between two sets of observations, whereas `pdist` calculates the pairwise distance between all observations in a single matrix.

The documentation of [`pdist2`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) specifies the correct syntax and meaning of the output distance matrix:

> `D = pdist2(X,Y)` returns a matrix D containing the Euclidean distances
>   between each pair of observations in the mx-by-n data matrix X and
>   my-by-n data matrix Y. Rows of X and Y correspond to observations,
>   columns correspond to variables. D is an mx-by-my matrix, with the
>   (i,j) entry equal to distance between observation i in X and
>   observation j in Y.

So, you should use this as follows:

```
D = pdist2(C1, C2);
```

*Note 1:* If you have find a function which almost does what you want (i.e. `pdist`) it is often useful to look into the `See Also` section of the manual and check if one of these may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should define more precisely what is "matching": should it be 1-to-1 or 1-to-many?

If it's 1-to-many (several centroids of C1 can be matched to the same centroid of C2) then using nearest-neighbors can help, [see `knnsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html).

If it's 1-to-1, then you'd have to use some greedy algorithm to map the closest centroids first (loop over the result of [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html?searchHighlight=pdist2&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)).

As for the plotting of the matches, it really depends on the nature of the data.
But one convenient way would be to do a PCA to go from 3D to 2D and then simply plot lines between centroids.